# Connect an iPad Pro to both Ethernet and HDMI

Tags: ipad, usb, hdmi, ethernet, lightning

Is it possible to connect the iPad Pro to both RJ-45 wired ethernet (data i/o) and HDMI out?

Note: [iPad Pro to ethernet is already possible](http://lifehacker.com/hack-together-a-way-to-connect-an-ipad-or-iphone-over-e-1770270331) - using the lightning to usb female camera adapter...

- but is it possible to daisy chain in the hdmi out...

Example:

```
                               -> hdmi out |                   <- ac
```

iPad Pro -> [lightning to HDMI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009WHV3BM) -> [lightning to usb-female](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009WHV3BM) -> [usb to ethernet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009WHV3BM)

- or some other technique?

Comment: Did you try it out? Otherwise you could buy an Lighting to Camera Adapter + USB Hub with Ethernet and Hdmi in it. I would love to know if this worked out.

Comment: it did not but maybe might work these days in newer iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I found through some searching around is this:

[Lightning port to USBc adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=lightning+to+usbc&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=103522256294&hvpos=1t1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6686653563936527137&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9033592&hvtargid=kwd-147687312316&ref=pd_sl_3rqy3f53t_e)

to

[Then USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b)

Then get a USB to ethernet.
I am not sure if that Multiport adapter works well having the HDMI and USB port accessed at the same time or if the iPad will even utilize all the conversions. But there are [examples](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/08/28/how-to-connect-an-ipad-to-ethernet/) of someone using a grocery cart of adapters to make something work on an iPad

Comment: Okay that's interesting trying it through lighting to usb c...